# Nodemailer Sendgrid on Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, sendgrid, nodemailer

i trying to send emails from my compute engine instance but nothing happen(no error message). When i send mails from my local pc i get the emails.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var options = {};
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    service: 'SendGrid',
    auth: {
        user: 'username',
        pass: 'password'
    }
}));
module.exports = {
    sendmailto : sendmailto
}

function sendmailto(emailfrom,emailto, message){

    var mailOptions = {
        from: emailfrom, // sender address
        to: emailto, // list of receivers
        subject: 'Monitoring', // Subject line
        text: message, // plaintext body
        html: '<b>Monitoring</b>' +
        '<p> '+message+'<p>' // html body
    };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
      if(error){
          return console.log(error);
      }else{
          console.log('Message send: ', + info.response);
      }

    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason be myself:) Service "Sendgrid use as standard port the 25 but is does not work with compute engine so i need to add the port 2525.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    service: 'SendGrid',
    port: '2525',
    auth: {
        user: 'username',
        pass: 'password'
    }
}));
```

Comment: Yup, Compute Engine blocks port 25 to prevent spam: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/